# React 16 Modal form update operation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am new to react-16 and have done with React-16 save and delete operation.when it comes to edit/update operation, I found difficulty in approach.1)when I hit on the update button, get modal open but values not getting shown in each field.2)how do i update form values in setState function after saving to them. Thanks.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {Form,FormGroup,FormControl,Col,Button,Modal,ButtonToolbar,Table} from "react-bootstrap";
class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: "",
      description: "",
      amount: "",
      date: "",
      show: false,
      formdata: []
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);
    this.hideModal = this.hideModal.bind(this);
    this.showEditModal = this.showEditModal.bind(this);
  }

  showModal() {
    this.setState({ show: true });
  }

  showEditModal(event) {
    this.setState({
      show: true,

      name: this.state.name.value,
      description: this.state.description.value,
      amount: this.state.amount.value,
      date: this.state.date.value
    });
  }

  hideModal() {
    this.setState({
      show: false,
      name: "",
      description: "",
      amount: "",
      date: ""
    });
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
      [event.target.description]: event.target.value,
      [event.target.amount]: event.target.value,
      [event.target.date]: event.target.value
    });
  }
  handleSubmit(event) {
    const formItem = {
      name: this.state.name,
      description: this.state.description,
      amount: this.state.amount,
      date: this.state.date
    };

    if (
      this.state.name === "" ||
      this.state.amount === "" ||
      this.state.date === ""
    ) {
      alert("Please fill mandatory filed");
    } else {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        formdata: prevState.formdata.concat(formItem)
      }));

      alert("form submited: ");

      this.setState({
        name: "",
        description: "",
        amount: "",
        date: ""
      });
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  deleteExpense(i) {
    alert("are you sure you want to Delete this item ?");
    this.setState({
      formdata: this.state.formdata.filter((item, index) => {
        return index !== i;
      })
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Welcome</p>

        <ButtonToolbar>
          <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>
            Add Expenses
          </Button>
          <Table striped bordered condensed hover>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>description</th>
                <th>amount</th>
                <th>date</th>
                <th>Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {this.state.formdata.map((item, i) => (
                <tr key={i}>
                  <td>{item.name}</td>
                  <td>{item.description}</td>
                  <td>{item.amount}</td>
                  <td>{item.date}</td>
                  <td>
                    <Button bsStyle="warning" onClick={this.showEditModal}>
                      Update
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                      bsStyle="danger"
                      onClick={() => this.deleteExpense(i)}
                    >
                      Delete
                    </Button>
                  </td>
                  <td />
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
          <Modal
            {...this.props}
            show={this.state.show}
            onHide={this.hideModal}
            dialogClassName="custom-modal"
          >
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
              <Modal.Title
                id="contained-modal-title-lg "
                className="text-center"
              >
                Add Expenses
              </Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
              <Form horizontal onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalEmail">
                  <Col smOffset={4} sm={4}>
                    <FormControl
                      type="Text"
                      placeholder="name"
                      name="name"
                      value={this.state.name}
                      onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    />
                  </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalPassword">
                  <Col smOffset={4} sm={4}>
                    <FormControl
                      type="description"
                      placeholder="description"
                      name="description"
                      value={this.state.description}
                      onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    />
                  </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalPassword">
                  <Col smOffset={4} sm={4}>
                    <FormControl
                      type="amount"
                      placeholder="amount"
                      name="amount"
                      value={this.state.amount}
                      onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    />
                  </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalPassword">
                  <Col smOffset={4} sm={4}>
                    <FormControl
                      type="date"
                      placeholder="date"
                      name="date"
                      value={this.state.date}
                      onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    />
                  </Col>
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup>
                  <Col smOffset={5} sm={4}>
                    <Button type="submit" bsStyle="primary">
                      Add
                    </Button>
                  </Col>
                </FormGroup>
              </Form>
            </Modal.Body>
          </Modal>
        </ButtonToolbar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Dashboard;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `openEditModal()` method, you will want to set the state values to the values of the record you want to edit (the one you clicked in the table). In this case, you will need to look up the selected item, update the state, and then open the modal. Like so:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {Form,FormGroup,FormControl,Col,Button,Modal,ButtonToolbar,Table} from "react-bootstrap";

class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: "",
      description: "",
      amount: "",
      date: "",
      show: false,
      formdata: []
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);
    this.hideModal = this.hideModal.bind(this);
    this.showEditModal = this.showEditModal.bind(this);
  }

  showModal() {
    this.setState({ show: true });
  }

  showEditModal(event, i) {
    const recordToEdit = this.state.formdata.filter((item, index) => {
      return index === i;
    })[0];

    this.setState({
      show: true,

      name: recordToEdit.name,
      description: recordToEdit.description,
      amount: recordToEdit.amount,
      date: recordToEdit.date
    });
  }

  hideModal() {
    this.setState({
      show: false,
      name: "",
      description: "",
      amount: "",
      date: ""
    });
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    // update the input that changed
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  }
  
  handleSubmit(event) {
    const formItem = {
      name: this.state.name,
      description: this.state.description,
      amount: this.state.amount,
      date: this.state.date
    };

    if (
      this.state.name === "" ||
      this.state.amount === "" ||
      this.state.date === ""
    ) {
      alert("Please fill mandatory filed");
    } else {
      if (this.state.formdata.filter(item => item.name === formItem.name).length > 0) {
        // update item
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          formdata: prevState.formdata.map(item => {
            if (item.name === formItem.name)
              return formItem;
            else
              return item;
          })
        }));

      } else {
        // add new item
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          formdata: prevState.formdata.concat(formItem)
        }));

      }

      alert("form submited: ");

      this.setState({
        name: "",
        description: "",
        amount: "",
        date: ""
      });
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  deleteExpense(i) {
    alert("are you sure you want to Delete this item ?");
    this.setState({
      formdata: this.state.formdata.filter((item, index) => {
        return index !== i;
      })
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Welcome</p>

        <ButtonToolbar>
          <Button bsStyle="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>
            Add Expenses
          </Button>
          <Table striped bordered condensed hover>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>description</th>
                <th>amount</th>
                <th>date</th>
                <th>Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {this.state.formdata.map((item, i) => (
                <tr key={i}>
                  <td>{item.name}</td>
                  <td>{item.description}</td>
                  <td>{item.amount}</td>
                  <td>{item.date}</td>
                  <td>
                    <Button bsStyle="warning" onClick={(e) => this.showEditModal(e, i)}>
                      Update
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                      bsStyle="danger"
                      onClick={() => this.deleteExpense(i)}
                    >
                      Delete
                    </Button>
                  </td>
                  <td />
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
          <Modal
            {...this.props}
            show={this.state.show}
            onHide={this.hideModal}
            dialogClassName="custom-modal"
          >
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
              <Modal.Title
                id="contained-modal-title-lg "
                className="text-center"
              >
                Add Expenses
              </Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
              <Form horizontal onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalEmail">
                  <Col smOffset={4} sm={4}>
                    <FormControl
                      type="Text"
                      placeholder="name"
                      name="name"
                      value={this.state.name}
                      onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    />
                  </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalPassword">
                  <Col smOffset={4} sm={4}>
                    <FormControl
                      type="description"
                      placeholder="description"
                      name="description"
                      value={this.state.description}
                      onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    />
                  </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalPassword">
                  <Col smOffset={4} sm={4}>
                    <FormControl
                      type="amount"
                      placeholder="amount"
                      name="amount"
                      value={this.state.amount}
                      onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    />
                  </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup controlId="formHorizontalPassword">
                  <Col smOffset={4} sm={4}>
                    <FormControl
                      type="date"
                      placeholder="date"
                      name="date"
                      value={this.state.date}
                      onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    />
                  </Col>
                </FormGroup>

                <FormGroup>
                  <Col smOffset={5} sm={4}>
                    <Button type="submit" bsStyle="primary">
                      Add
                    </Button>
                  </Col>
                </FormGroup>
              </Form>
            </Modal.Body>
          </Modal>
        </ButtonToolbar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Dashboard;
```

Notice that I'm passing the index to the `showEditModal()` function so I can update the state with the selected record. Also, I'm updating the field in the `handleInputChange()` method using the `name="field_name"` property on each form input.

Side note: per the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html):

> We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state.

Consider using a unique ID for each record rather than the index provided by the map function.

Comment: Thanks it solve's the first problem but for the second problem when I update it with new values, it makes new entry instead of updating old entries.

Comment: That's because you're using `.concat()` on the previous state, which simply adds the item to the end of the array. I've updated my answer to provide one way of updating the item in the state.

Comment: I replaced with updated code but when I add the values and save.it does not make any entries at all.

Comment: I apologize. I didn't realize you were adding and updating in the same event. I have update my code to reflect this change.

Comment: i get the error when i save i gets an error as cannot read property of filter undefined and page refreshes very quickly and no data gets saved .

Comment: Sorry, had a typo. Fixed now

Comment: error has gone but data does not save on save button.

Comment: Updated. Used `.concat()` to return the updated array for add, and checking the length of the filter to determine if the record exists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161074/discussion-between-amar-ghodke-and-t-porter).